# How do I create a new application icon?

Tags: launcher, icons, packaging, mate

I'm creating a .deb package for an application (not for public distribution) and want to have an icon for the application for the taskbar, menu, dock, etc. My application's `.desktop` file has a line to specify icons, like:

```
Icon=preferences-desktop-keyboard
```

But how and where do you actually create a new icon?

Let's say I wanted to take an existing icon like the ImageMagick icon shown in `/usr/share/applications/ImageMagick`. The `display.im6.desktop` file (which is what actually opens when you try to edit `/usr/share/applications/ImageMagick`) has the line `Icon=display.im6`.

Ok, great. Since there's no full path, how do I find the graphics file for `display.im6`? What format is it in? Or are these dynamic files where there's a set of them for different sizes?

Then, I assume I can edit it/them in either GIMP or Inkscape?

Now, what format do I export it as, and to where? And do I need to create some type of meta file so that I can add a line to my application's launcher that reads `Icon=myicon` and the system will know where to get the icon from?

**Update**

`locate display.im6` shows about 15 entries. There seems to be two themes, and a bunch of different sizes including one called scalable. I can't create an icon for each theme the user might have, so I guess I need to create a default icon somewhere? Or do I need a set of them in all the sizes? Or can I just create a scalable file and it will figure it out?

**Update 2**

I used `locate` to find an existing icon in .svg format and edited in inkscape. I tried adding it to the `.desktop` file with the full path:

```
Icon=/opt/myapp/lib/myapp-51.0.2/icons/myapp.svg
```

And the `.desktop` file has this icon now, but when you install the `.desktop` launcher into `/usr/share/applications/` the luancher on the main menu has a red "missing icon" icon.

so I'm still not sure how you create a specify an icon stack with the different file formats and sizes and where those files get placed, and how you attach the set to the `.desktop` file.

Comment: Run `sudo updatedb`, then run `locate display.im6`. It'll probably be somewhere in `/usr/share/icons`. As far as creating your own, I don't know the specifics, but it looks like at the very least both SVG and PNG files are used.

Answer (score 2):

- It is recommended to install the icon into:

  `/usr/share/pixmaps/`

  or: `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/icons`

  Then declare it in the `.desktop` file as (without extension):

  ```
  Icon=filename
  ```
- Only if you have a flat package that installed to `/opt` folder, then you have to use the absolute path:

  ```
  Icon=/opt/fullpath/filename.ext
  ```

BTW, If it didn't work, possibly you have a permission issue. Icons should be readable by all.

**Reference:** [freedesktop.org - Icon Theme Specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html#directory_layout)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to manually specify the image file:

```
Icon=/usr/share/icons/MYPROGRAM/MYICON.png
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the various sizes though, and specifying an svg file in the `Icon` property results in a missing icon on the applications menu.