# Providing an Icon for the taskbar for a java application

Tags: java, icons, taskbar

I have a java application packaged as an executable file with [JavaPackager](https://github.com/fvarrui/JavaPackager). The content of the tar.gz file is:

- a PNG file (provided by me - 128px/128px )
- a folder with all the .jar libs
- an executable file (bash shell)

When that application is executing, its icon is displayed in the taskbar, but in an ugly way, like an enlarged small icon:

[image: Application's icon in the taskbar]

[Most questions/answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884109/how-do-i-create-a-new-application-icon) about taskbar icons deal with editing manually a `myapplication.desktop` file.

I'd like to find an automated solution. Where the icon is directly correct, even at other DPI's, without requiring any user action.

What would it be ? Adding other icons, at other sizes ? Adding in the package another file ?

EDIT:

I've finally added a `myapplication.desktop` file. And if the icon is properly rendered in the application menu

[image: Icon in the application menu]

it keeps being wrongly rendered in the taskbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is having the right `xxx.desktop` file.

The application is a java application and is known by the OS under its **main class name**. So if the main class of the application is `foo.bar.MyApplication.class` the OS knows the application as `foo-bar-MyApplication`.

So the solution is to create the following file:

```
~/.local/share/applications/foo-bar-MyApplication.desktop
```

With the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=My Wonderful Application
Icon=/path/to/a/wondefull/icon.png
```

This is the simplest solution. JavaPackager is, at this stage, not involved. This is achieved by the Java code itself.